# blocked by software restriction policies?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Alguem ja se deparou com esta mensagem ao abrir o Visual Sdudio??

> \packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\init.ps1 
>   cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy.
>   At line:1 char:45
>   + $__pc_args=@(); $input|%{$__pc_args+=$_}; & 'D:\Fontes\Projetos Particulares\Vis ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Poderia me ajudar a solucionar isso?

Comment: Ao abrir um projeto? Ou mesmo sem nenhum projeto ele dá esse erro? Já tentou executar o VS como administrador?

Comment: Sim ao abrir um projeto... Qualquer um. E eu ja coloquei automatico abrir como adm o VS @jbueno

Comment: Já trocou a política de execução no power shell?

Comment: Executei o comando PM> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted e não esta dando erro mais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Package Manager Console, digite o seguinte:

```
PM> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Não há problemas em reduzir a política de restrição de scripts em uma máquina de desenvolvimento.

Se não funcionar de primeira, experimente executar o Visual Studio como administrador e tente novamente.

Além disso, se não for uma restrição de projeto, é até melhor atualizar o Entity Framework. A versão 6 não tem essa restrição.

Comment: preciso fazer isso sempre!?

Comment: Não. Pro Entity Framework 6 nunca precisei fazer.

Comment: Bom... Qualquer coisa tbem, executo o comando novamente. Vlws @Cigano.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso este problema ocorreu porque havia um certificado da Microsoft com problema. Para resolver vá em Internet Options => Content => Certificates  na aba Untrusted Publishers e remova Microsoft Corporation.
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7158